# Any ways to export OpenTelemetry (Otel) data directly from a C# application to the Azure Data Explorer (ADX) backend?

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer, open-telemetry, adx, open-telemetry-collector

I'm trying to find a way to export OpenTelemetry (Otel) data directly from a C# application to the Azure Data Explorer (ADX) backend. My main goal is to find a way that bypasses the need of setting up an OpenTelemetry Collector service/agent. If you could provide any guidance on this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The collector has two modes.  See Collector paragraph  : https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/what-is-opentelemetry-2/

Comment: Appreciate your input, but my initial query was specifically about finding a solution that doesn't require using a collector. Running it on each user's system or even hosting it as a service introduces added complexity we're trying to avoid. We don't want our users to deal with a background agent, nor do we wish to manage another service layer. Hence, we're exploring options that avoid the need for a collector. We are interested in finding a direct exporter for ADX if any

Comment: Look at the figure OpenTelemetry Components.  Where are you going to bypass the normal processing?

Comment: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/deployment/no-collector/

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Exporter that will push the data from the C# app. There's nothing pre-built or out of the box for it from what I'm aware.

Exporters are fairly each to create, you'll just need to do the mapping to the ADX ingest endpoints.